# Update object values that changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a the following Situation:

There is a profile section in my application where users can update their profile data. Therefore I have a mvc form where users can add additional infos or modify their data. In my form submit function I am receiving a user object that is mostly filled out but not completely (some of the values are null because I am using identity service and i don't want the user to change the password hash for example).

Now here is my question:

How can I update my user object without writing something like this: (profileData.User is the submitted user)

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(profileData.User.Id);
user.Email = profileData.User.Email;
user.Salutation = profileData.User.Salutation;
user.FirstName = profileData.User.FirstName;
user.LastName = profileData.User.LastName;
...
var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

I obviously cannot use this as this would override the all the fields that are not set in the submitted user:

```
var user = profileData.User
```

Is there a way to update my user object without overriding all the fields?

Comment: You can try to use AutoMapper library to map properties between your domain objects /DTOs

Comment: I don't get the question. Why would you assign fields that are not in the form?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well that's the point. I have a form where the user can change his profile data such as his E-Mail address. If he saves the data a user object is posted to the controller. This object does not contain every field of the user, it only contains the data that was displayed in the form. For example: The password hash is not displayed in the form, therefore it is not in the posted data. I would have to assign each value like in my example (user.Email = ..., user.Firstname = ...). I was wonderin whether or not there is a way to simplify this and not assign each value independendly.

Comment: What about `IsModified` for properties? Usage: `context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Email).IsModified = true;` or `context.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Password).IsModified = false;`

Answer (score 0):

One of the good reasons for using DTOs is that you can have a different one for every get/update pair of functions.  Rather than having one 'catch-all' update function, why not have one that will one update the properties you can change in each form.   Yes, you will end up with lots of classes and functions, but you also get simple to test, single use functions that do one job well (and you don't get the sort of problems you are asking about).

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(profileData.User.Id);
user.Email = profileData.User.Email;
user.Salutation = profileData.User.Salutation;
user.FirstName = profileData.User.FirstName;
user.LastName = profileData.User.LastName;

var result = await _userManager.UpdateProfileAsync(user); <-- Only updates the 'profile' fields
```

I would also go some way to argue that `FindByIdAsync` should not be returning password/salt etc.  Perhaps you should have a function `FindProfileByIdAsync`.